# Select linestrings containing points with duplicating M coordinates in postgis

Tags: postgis, postgresql, linestring, dimensions

I have a table of LineStringM geometries. Some of lines have points with same measure (M coordinate). This is a bug in initial data, that I want to clean somehow.
So I need to:
1. Select all records, containing linestrings with vertexes having duplicating M values.
2. Correct theese values automatically, using M values from their neighbor vertexes.
How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first part of the question. Could be a one-liner, but I don't yet know how to add a counter to selection.

```
--Getting all vertexes with measures   
create table public.vertex_tab as
select
     lin_id 
     ,st_npoints(geom) as pnt_count
     ,generate_series(1, ST_NPoints(geom)) as pnt_num
     ,ST_PointN(geom, generate_series(1, ST_NPoints(geom))) as pnt_geom
     ,ST_M(ST_PointN(geom, generate_series(1, ST_NPoints(geom)))) as pnt_measure
     ,ST_X(ST_Transform(ST_PointN(geom, generate_series(1, ST_NPoints(geom))),4326)) as lon
     ,ST_Y(ST_Transform(ST_PointN(geom, generate_series(1, ST_NPoints(geom))),4326)) as lat
    from 
    public.lin_tab;

--Numbering vertexes
alter table public.vertex_tab add column gid serial not null;

--Selecting duplicates
select 
     a.gid
     ,a.lin_id
     ,a.pnt_geom
     ,a.pnt_measure
     ,a.pnt_num 
     ,a.lon
     ,a.lat
     ,b.gid as problem_with
     ,b.num as problem_num
from 
    public.vertex_tab as a
    ,public.vertex_tab as b
where 
    a.lin_id=b.lin_id and 
    NOT ST_Equals(a.pnt_geom, b.pnt_geom) and 
    a.gid!=b.gid  and --double check 
                      --another one is a.pnt_num!=b.pnt_num and
    a.pnt_measure=b.pnt_measure;
```

Comment: You can make this terser and faster using ST_DumpPoints() (also includes vertex identifying info)